# Apache Cordova: no build targets listed when attempting to create new project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am using eclipse first of all with windows 7

Using this [tutorial](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) for getting started with cordova for android. Got all the way to seection 4 - "select the directory of `<project_folder_path>`" I did that and everything looks good except for one problem. I get a big red x that says an SDK target must be specified. Under the build target section there are no targets available.

How do i get past this